# ¿Cómo agregar automáticamente un campo de texto a un input?

Tags: php, javascript, html

hoy quisiera preguntarles como resolver el siguiente inconveniente y lo voy a plantear de la siguiente manera:

Tengo una caja de texto donde ingresaría un numero cualquiera por ejemplo 40 y al dar en guardar se almacene como 40-2**020** o 40-**INICIAL**, quisiera saber como añadir automáticamente ese -2020 o -INICIAL, aun no he realizado código, pero quisiera saber si ustedes tiene alguna idea de como realizarlo.

```
<div class="row">

                 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                 <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="nproyecto" class="col-form-label"><strong>PROYECTO:</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nproyecto" placeholder="PROYECTO">



                 </div>
```

Intente con esto pero nada

```
 <label for="nproyecto" class="col-form-label"><strong>PROYECTO:</strong></label>
                        <?php if(isset($_GET['nproyecto1']))
                          $_GET['nproyecto1'].='-2020';
                          else $_GET['nproyecto1']='';?>
                        <form>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nproyecto" name="nproyecto1"  value="<?=$_GET['nproyecto1']?>">
                         </form>
```

Comment: Saludos, te recomiendo que si tienes algo avanzado lo adjuntes modificando tu pregunta pregunta para poder colaborarte con tu problema de una forma mas precisa. Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para más información. ;)

Comment: a ver amigo ayúdame porfa

Comment: Edita el título de la pregunta, considera que escribir en mayúsculas == gritar. Gracias por la comprensión :D

Comment: Revisa po favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como en las etiquetas de la pregunta no indicas JS, entiendo que lo quieres hacer en backend, por lo que te propongo algo así:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['variable']))
    $_GET['variable'].='-2020';
else $_GET['variable']='';
?>
<form>
    <input name="variable" value="<?=$_GET['variable']?>">
    <button>Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Déjame tus dudas en los comentarios para documentar la respuesta lo mejor posible.

Comment: Gracias edite mi pregunta y agregue el código. que estoy haciendo.

Comment: Observa que te falta la etiqueta `form` y el atributo `name`,  esos dos elementos son imprescindibles